# Unable to start after 13.04 > 13.10 update

Tags: 13.04, updates, 13.10

At the end of the update process, click on the *Restart* button had no visible effect whatsoever. After waiting 5 to 10 minutes, I decided to reboot the computer manually.

Since then, I rebooted a good dozen times (not with the hope that it would work but with the hope of reading the messages) with the same non-result and the same symptoms:

1. I get the ASCII text-on-purple

   ```
   Ubuntu  13.10
   .   .   .   .
   ```

   splash screen with these messages:

   ```
   * Restoring resolver state...                    [OK]
   * Starting crash report submission daemon        [OK]
   * Starting CUPS printing spooler/server          [OK]
   ```
2. Everything disappears.
3. The whole process hangs at a purple screen with the mouse cursor right in the middle. At this point, I'm unable to use the mouse *and* the keyboard.

Booting from a 12.04 CD works perfectly, Disk Utility says that all my disks are OK and I can mount my main partition without problems.

Something obviously went wrong at the end of the upgrade but I have no idea what. I'd appreciate any pointer.

This is the kind of moment where you *really* think "Next time, I'll separate my `/home` partition for sure".

My machine is an aging but working Dell Inspiron 530 with an Intel Core Duo E2160 processor, 2 GHz of RAM and an ATI Radeon HD3650 video card.

Thanks.

(EDIT)

I had a 12.04 CD in a drawer so I spent the whole day doing the upgrade dance:

```
12.04 -> 12.10 -> 13.04 -> 13.10
```

Everything went well during the three first steps but I get the same result after the 13.10 upgrade.

Comment: Do you have the Linux headers and the Linux image installed and updated, then do you have the graphical gnome installed so everything isn't terminal based, so you're saying the login isn't booting up or the Linux imagine isn't booting up, sounds like you need to boot up into recovery mode and reinstall the Linux image and Linux headers

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the `fglrx-legacy` package? Try to remove it and reboot:

1. Enter `tty1` using `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, and log in.
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove fglrx-legacy
   ```
3. reboot

This may fix your problem, although you won't have the ATI Catalyst driver anymore.

I had a similar problem, and the above method fixed it, thanks to this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/361361/204380

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your link. Unfortunately, the keyboard doesn't work so I can't enter any of the ttys.

Comment: @romainl You need to select "Recovery mode" from the grub selection menu during boot.

Comment: Never use fglrx with Radeon, AMD dropped fglrx for Radeon drivers, with newer Radeon drivers AMD has their own support, if you use fglrx with Radeon you'll have to degrade xorg to match it, and then you'll face many many problems, if you never downgraded fglrx then the fglrx module will boot you into a black screen

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem. 
I started in security mode, enabled network and then went to console as root. I tried to remove *fglrx* but it was absent. I guess kubuntu removed it when I said YES to 'want to remove packages no longer used?'

I installed the fglrx package and restarted the computer. Everything was in order.